# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Exception Handling

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am working on an application where the event causes spring data repository to save data;

```
Entity entity = entityRepository.save((Entity) event.getPayload());
```

this code can throw various exceptions, like DataIntegrityViolationException which is runtime exception.

**My Question** is how to

- Handle such an exception and
- generate a Message with Payload caused this error
- with Exception,
- allowing Producer to take an action.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom error handler to the binding's listener container...

```java
@Bean
ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<?, ?>> customizer() {
    return (container, dest, group) -> {
        if (group.equals("theOneIWant")) {
            container.setErrorHandler( ... );
        }
    };
}
```